# pandas calculate delta time

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Here's some code where that will generate some random data, and chart plus lines representing 30th & 90th percentiles.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                                       
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(10)  # added for reproductibility                                                                                                                                                                 

rng = pd.date_range('10/9/2018 00:00', periods=10, freq='1H') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 100, 10)}, index=rng)                                                                                                                   
df.plot()    

plt.axhline(df.quantile(0.3)[0], linestyle="--", color="g")                                                                                                                                                    
plt.axhline(df.quantile(0.90)[0], linestyle="--", color="r")                                                                                                                                                    

plt.show()
```

Outputs: (minus the highlighted part of the chart)

[image]

Im trying to figure out if its possible to calculate the time in the data it takes to reach (highlighted yellow) from green to the red line.

I can manually enter in the data:

```
minStart = df.loc[df['Random_Number'] < 18].index[0]

maxStart = df.loc[df['Random_Number'] > 90].index[0]

hours = maxStart - minStart
hours
```

Which will output:

```
Timedelta('0 days 05:00:00')
```

But if I attempt to use:

```
minStart = df.loc[df['Random_Number'] < df.quantile(0.3)].index[0]

maxStart = df.loc[df['Random_Number'] > df.quantile(0.90)].index[0]

hours = maxStart - minStart
hours
```

This will throw an `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Would there be a better method to madness? Ideally it would be nice to create some sort of an algorithm that can calculate delta Time to it takes to go from 30th - 90th percentile and then delta back from 90th - 30th.. But I may have to put some thought towards how that could be accomplished..

Comment: replace `df.quantile(number)` by `df.quantile(number)[0]` and see if it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
minStart = df.loc[df['Random_Number'] < df.quantile(0.3)[0]].index[0]

maxStart = df.loc[df['Random_Number'] > df.quantile(0.90)[0]].index[0]

hours = maxStart - minStart
hours
```

df.quantile doesn't return a number so you need to get the first entry of it